# Is it possible to use SoundCloud HTML5 Widget API from non-HTTPS domain?

Tags: soundcloud

So, apparently due to a recent switch, all SoundCloud API and widget requests are routed through HTTPS. Due to this, any attempt to use the Widget API (http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget) from a non-HTTPS domain throws the following error in Chrome:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://foobar.com/ from 
frame with URL https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?
url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F7659975. The frame requesting 
access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 
'http'. Protocols must match.
```

There is apparently an Chromium [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17325) being tracked concerning this issue. So, my question is: is it possible to use the HTML5 Widget API currently, or is this a blocking issue?

Comment: i think this has anything to do with Use of SoundCloud Widget API.
there are errors thrown, but you can still control widget from your script.

and it's not chromium issue, you'll find this error on most browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this *is* an issue with Chromium, it doesn't really prevent any kind of use of iframe including `postMessage`, which is used to control the HTML5 widget.